# JavaMail to minecraft

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, minecraft

My friends and I have minecraft server and we want to add JavaMail plugin with `Maven` , We added 2 jar files:

Mail.jar

Activation.jar

With this code:

```
package com.parlagames;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
 import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class App {






public  void AppVoid(String host, String port,final String userName,final String password, String[] toAddress, String subject, String message) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
    props.put("mail.smtp.port",port);

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
              new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(userName, password);
                }
              });

    try {

        Message SendMessage = new MimeMessage(session);
        SendMessage.setFrom(new InternetAddress(userName)); 
        for(int i=0;i<toAddress.length;i++) {
        SendMessage.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
            InternetAddress.parse(toAddress[i]));

        SendMessage.setSubject(subject);
        SendMessage.setContent(message, "text/html; charset=utf-8");


        Transport.send(SendMessage);
        }

        System.out.println("Sent");

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);



}
}
}
```

When we start the plugin in his server it shows an error that it doesn't identify the class

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/parlagames/App
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.PluginClassLoader.findClass(PluginClassLoader.java:101) ~[spigot-1.11.2.jar:git-Spigot-3fb9445-6e3cec8]
```

Why does it happend? we need to have the maven by the way

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to add this line of code to the plugin:

```
public void onEnable()
```

and this code

```
public void onDisable()
```

It also seems that you don't have a main class. A main class is declared at plugin.yml. Try finding the part that says "main:" and change it to the class that has the "onEnable()" and "onDisable()". Also add `extends JavaPlugin` as someone said before

Answer (score 0):

Is `App` the main class of your plugin ? If so, it you need to make it extend the `JavaPlugin` class like this :

```
public class MyPlugin extends JavaPlugin {

    public void onEnable() {

    }

    public void onDisable() {

    }

}
```

If you have trouble understanding of the bukkit/spigot API, I would suggest to start learning from the docs ([here](https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/creating-a-blank-spigot-plugin-in-eclipse) is a reference guide for the basics).

Comment: The code in the post is the main class but we add this jar file to his server. and when we try to call the method it wont run

Comment: @Dany123 you must extend JavaPlugin as I have stated multiple times you are not.